# Can we hide some rows in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Say we retrieve table data from a php code.

1- Without delete and restore particular rows from the table and,
2- Without having a column "`hidden`" (values are 0 or 1) and using the query 
`SELECT ..... WHERE....AND hidden=0`

Is it possible to temporary "hide" some of the rows ?
Or else what is the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative would be to create a `VIEW` which does not include the unwanted rows; that might be better if the requirement is of a (semi-)permanent nature. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) for more.

Comment: anyway I'll have to have a different name for the View ( not the same as Table name )right? Then we need to modify the query .But seems in any case I need to modify the query .This might be the simplest solution since we only need to change `SELECT FROM xxxxx` part.

Answer (score 2):

How do you know which rows you want to remove? For example, if you know the id for each of the rows you could append an exclusion to your queries

```
AND id NOT IN (4,9,28)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WHERE id NOT IN`

```
SELECT * FROM talName WHERE id NOT IN (1, 3)

+----+---------+-----+
| id |  name   | age |
+----+---------+-----+
|  2 | John    |  23 |
|  4 | Mary    |  21 |
|  5 | Michael |  26 |
+----+---------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to hide without deleting, since the mark for hidden is already done (hidden = 1).

Although the correct way is to alter the first query, since you won't retrieve unwanted data, you can:

- Query on the query, adding the 'where hidden=0' part
- Filter the data inside the script that handles the table
- Add a view on the database that is pre-filtering (where hidden=0)
- Filter the data on the client (start as hidden everything and using jquery show what you want (not recommended as a solution though)

Comment: I think the asker is saying they don't want to use a "hidden" column, rather than that they have one.

Comment: I was thinking that he can't modify original query!

Comment: '...Without having a column "hidden"...' - so there is no hidden column.